# windows 7 truecrypt boot loader

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, truecrypt

my entire disk was encrypted with truecrypt. When i was working on, the pc shutdown immediately. I try to turn it on. Truecrypt boot loader password is asked. I enter the pwd correctly but i can only see windows repair screen. And the partitions are seemed as null. i can only see x: partition that is about boot loader as i guess. can you help me how i can get my operating system back? Thank you.

Comment: If you have the TC boot recovery disk or whatever it's called that you create during the encryption process, boot to it and see if it'll allow you any further (or potentially decrypt if needed). You can also look for a Linux distro with TrueCrypt, boot to it, then mount the volume(s) with TC from it to recover the needed data and copy it to other media. You can use the Linux distro with GParted and/or other tools to run disk diag and tests as well. so find a live OS which has TC so you can mount and decrypt at least to get the data copied elsewhere for sure though.

Comment: @ModeratorImpersonator sounds like a perfect answer to me.